# A simple probability proof (?) concerning P(AB) given P(A)=P(B)=p

Tags: probability

I was asked to prove whether it's true or false that

$$ \mbox{If}\;\; P(A)=P(B)=p,\;\; \mbox{then}\;\; P(AB)\le p^2 $$

but I'm lost...

I tried: $P(AB) \le P(A) = p \le p^2$, then dividing by $P(A)$ we have: $1 = 1 \le 1^2$ so it's only true if $P(A) = P(B) = p = 1$...

But I think I've gone wrong...

Comment: a good way to think about this is with Venn diagrams, to see what is and isn't possible. Think about the circles for A and B being completely separate and then coming together and overlapping, until eventually the circles are coincident (as in @Voldemort's answer)

Comment: @TooTone Thanks for your comment and editing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's false. Take $A=B$ with $P(A)=p < 1$. Then $P(A \cap A)=p>p^2$.